# Sum of Decimal (time) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table which has 4 rows and values are

```
6.30
6.30
6.30
6.30
```

Now i want to do summation of the column.

I have tried below code

```
Select SUM(Time) from #temp
```

but i am getting 25.20 as a reault.

But the above values are in hh.mm

And i want the result as 26.

How can i achieve this in sql.?

Comment: What is the datatype of the time column? Please tell me datetime or smalldatetime or datetime2...

Comment: Looks like your data is decimal data type. Is your format ever go over 24 hours?  For example: 30.50?

Comment: datatype of my column is Decimal(18,2).

Comment: @AshleyLee No , it won't go over 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to modify Gordon's suggestion:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (time DECIMAL(18,2))
INSERT INTO #test (time) VALUES (4.2)
INSERT INTO #test (time) VALUES (4.2)
INSERT INTO #test (time) VALUES (4.2)
INSERT INTO #test (time) VALUES (4.2)

select CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),
    floor(sum(floor(time)) + sum(time - floor(time)) * 100.0/60)/1 +
       ((sum(floor(time))/1 + sum(time - floor(time)) * 100.0/60) % 1) * 60.0/100
    )
FROM #test
```

If you're summing to a value that doesn't equal an exact hour, it's going to round off.  (For the above data, this SQL will give you 17.20 instead of 17, to match your requirements (17 hours and 20 minutes).  For the data in the original question, both answers will return the same value).  This will preserve the full time as well as convert the data back to a DECIMAL(18,2).

Comment: For the above example, it should give 17.20 as a result

Comment: Updated to meet your requirements.  This returns 17.20.

Comment: Hello I also used your Solution but can you please Explain me how this query will work? No Doubt your query working perfectly but i just want to know the flow of query.

Comment: The 1st line is responsible for the hours.  It uses floor to get 16 hours, as well as convert the 4 .2 values to hours and minutes (1.33), then sums only hours.  The 2nd line uses a similar calculation to get only the minutes, converts the minutes back to decimal (33 min to .2).  The 100.0/60 allows you to convert from decimal to minutes in order to sum the time, then convert it back with 60.0/100.  Does that help?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select sum(floor(time)) + sum(time - floor(time)) * 100.0/60
```

This adds the hour and minute parts separately.

The interpretation of the results is as decimal hours.  If you want to convert this back to hours and minutes:

```
select floor(sum(floor(time)) + sum(time - floor(time)) * 100.0/60) +
       ((sum(floor(time)) + sum(time - floor(time)) * 100.0/60) % 1) * 60.0/100
```

Comment: Not working for all values.
For 4.2,4.2,4.2,4.2, it is not working fine.

Comment: That should return 0.8 * 100 / 60 = 1.33 hours.  That seems correct to me.

Comment: if you do sum of the above, then the total hours is  16hours and 80 mins., so it should return 17hours and 20mins

Comment: That is what this expression returns.  Here is there SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/570b0/1.

Comment: it is giving 17hours and 33mins

Comment: @PrashantBhojani . . . No.  It is returning 17.33 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Record the value in the DB simply in terms minutes? Ie 1Hr 20min = 80

Comment: This assumes the OP has write access to the data.  Maybe OP doesn't own the data, but is just selecting from it, and altering the format it's stored in could be a breaking change.

Comment: Maybe - but it's an answer, not a decree. The OP is free to accept / reject my advice as he feels fit based on his environment...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ceiling(sum(time))
FROM   #temp
```

Comment: This only works for the example given. Not other values

Answer (score -1):

You can use the built in functions time_to_sec and then sec_to_time. Here is the code in mysql:

```
create temporary table tmp (t1 time);
insert tmp values('6:30');
insert tmp values('6:30');
insert tmp values('6:30');
insert tmp values('6:30');
select sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(t1))) from tmp
```

which yields: '26:00:00'

Comment: This answer needs improvement.  Don't just post code with nothing else, and format code correctly.

Comment: Ok fixed my query. Seems like a simple  solution.

Comment: I don't see any improvement.  You haven't explained what your code does, and the code is not [properly formatted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: I tried the above in mysql and it works. So everything is properly formatted.  Seems like the simplest answer.

Comment: The tag on the question is "sql-server-2008".  This may work in mySQL, but does not work in SQL Server.